# my collectionView function( sizeForItemAt indexPath ) does'nt work

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Hi engineers and good luck , well basically I want to resize my collectionView photos in a row but when I use the method of collectionView that called sizeForItemAt indexPath it isn't work for me on simulator .
before I use this function this is my simulator :

[image]

and this is my viewDidLoad and function code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("\n iid is \(cid)")
     fetchOffer()
     collectionView.dataSource = self
     collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView , layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout , sizeForItemAt indexPath : IndexPath ) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
}
```

and after use those , my simulator show me this :

[image]

So anyOne have an idea about this matter?

Comment: Set estimation size to none from the storyboard.

Comment: I set it but still not worked for me

Comment: have you added this delegate UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Comment: also remove this line ```  collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()```

Comment: @RajaKishan yes thank you brother it worked but still I have a problem that photos on simulator are not in a row , each photo blow each photo

Comment: have you used any flowlayout ?

Comment: @RajaKishan actually I tried use that before in extension but I had error, so how can I use better flowlayout in code?

Comment: i don't think it will called `layout collectionViewLayout`. please check and le me know

Comment: @RB's I'm sure that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("\n iid is \(cid)")
     fetchOffer()
     collectionView.dataSource = self
     collectionView.delegate = self

}
}
```

you need to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your `UIViewController` and it(`layout collectionViewLayout`) will be called.

check out and let me know if you find any issue here.

Comment: thanks a lot brother , now I have a result that I want , I hope you get useful and helpful answer for your questions

Comment: @Alikazemi your welcome:). any other query you have about `UICollectionView`?.

Comment: not now , if I have a question about that I mention here the like of new question

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the delegate method:

> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView , layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout , sizeForItemAt indexPath : IndexPath ) -> CGSize {
> return CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
> }

and instead rely on the intrinsic size of the content (i.e. the UIImageView and UILabel you have in the simulator). If you set the size of the content inside relative to your superview then the CollectionViewCell will *self size* appropriately.

Comment: When you configure your UI use auto layout constraints, UIStackviews, or frame (or combination) to set the individual elements of your UI components.